# Reference a field on a form within a query using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an Access 2007 database that will be housing tables which refer to the bill of materials for multiple products.  On the main form I want a user to be able to select one of the products - OK, easy.  Now, I want two queries to run once they press a button after choosing their product from a dropdown.  The first query is a simple delete query to delete all information on a table.  The second query is where I'm having my issue with my SQL syntax.  I want the information from a static table to be appended to the table where the delete query just removed everything from.

Now, each table that houses the bill of material for each product is labeled with the product's name.  So I want the dropdown (`combo0`) to be the reference point for the table name in the `FROM` clause within the SQL string.  Code is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO tblTempSassyInfo (Concat, TableName, AddressName, PartNumber, [L/R], FeederSize, QtyPerBoard, SASSYname, RawBoard)
SELECT TableName & AddressName & PartNumber, TableName, AddressName, PartNumber, [L/R], FeederSize, QtyPerBoard, SassyName, RawBoard
FROM [FORMS]![DASHBOARD]![Combo0];
```

So you can see where I'm trying to reference the product name in the dropdown on the form as the table name.  Please let me know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"...  I'm trying to reference the product name in the dropdown on the form as the table name. Please let me know if this is possible."*

It is not possible with Access SQL.

The db engine can only accept the actual table name --- it isn't equipped to reference a form control to find the table name nor to accept any other type of parameter to obtain the table name.

You could change the query to include your combo's value as the table name and then rewrite the SQL from the combo's after update event.

```vba
"SELECT * FROM [" & [FORMS]![DASHBOARD]![Combo0] & "]"
```

A similar approach could keep Access happy.  But it may not be the best fit for your application.

Comment: What do you think about suggesting `Select` `Case` and reference the Combobox? The user can narrow down the 'Append Query' per `Case` and more accurately insert records into the appropriate table. I know the user has not implied that this method aligns with his/her project, but I am wondering if that would be an alternative to your suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, Mark, but I don't understand.  Can you flesh out your suggestion in the form of an answer?

Comment: Sure - see my post. (Delete if I am totally wrong, please!) @HansUp

Comment: @MarkLaREZZA  Yes, thanks, I understand now.  I believe your approach should work.  Perhaps his choice will be driven by number of tables.  I don't know how many there are or why there is more than one.

Comment: I second your last point. "I don't know why there is more than one." I am clueless to that as well. @HansUp - I have a quick question. Where did you learn SQL? I'm trying to learn more advanced SQL, and you've helped answer some of my questions regarding SQL, and I don't know where/how else to ask!

Comment: Started with SQL in FoxPro last century.  Later came Oracle, PostGres, and SQL Server.  Started Access in 2005.  I don't really know what to suggest for learning SQL.  I've heard *SQL for Smarties* by Joe Celko is well-regarded.

Comment: There is more than one table because each table house a "recipe" to build a specific product.  I know I could merely indicate which product each component/location/address/quantity belongs to with another column, however this will provide a neater approach as the bills will have to be updated from time to time.  Rather than running a separate update query or manually editing a mass table I would rather keep 100 separate tables.  One for each product.

Comment: @HansUp I think this is the best solution although I cannot seem to get it to work the way it is written. Using VBA this is what I've put together. Note: Message boxes are for test purposes.  
  
`Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSQL1 As String
Dim strSQL2 As String

strSQL = "DELETE * FROM tblTempSassyInfo;"
DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

strSQL1 = [Forms]![DASHBOARD]![Combo0]
MsgBox (strSQL1)

strSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM [" & strSQL1 & "]"
MsgBox (strSQL2)
                                                                            
DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL2)`

Comment: I was unclear.  Take your original `INSERT` query and replace the `FROM` clause with this: `FROM [" & strSQL1 & "]"`

Comment: Trying this still doesn't work:    

`strSQL1 = [Forms]![DASHBOARD]![Combo0]
MsgBox (strSQL1)

strSQL2 = "INSERT INTO tblTempSassyInfo (Concat) SELECT (" & PartNumber & ") FROM [" & strSQL1 & "]"
MsgBox (strSQL2)`  

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Seems to me this should work...

Comment: I don't spot the problem.  Is there an error message?  If no error, but no `INSERT` happens either, add `Debug.Print strSQL2` and check the statement text in the Immediate window.  You can copy the text and then paste into SQL View of a new Access query for testing.  Hopefully that will shed some light on the problem.

Comment: @HansUp I'm getting the 2342 runtime error "A RunSQL action requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement."

Comment: I don't see any `RunSQL` in your most recent code fragment.  Please edit your question to add the code which produces that error.

Comment: Sorry here is the fragment including the last `RunSQL` command.

`strSQL1 = [Forms]![DASHBOARD]![Combo0]
MsgBox (strSQL1)

strSQL2 = "INSERT INTO tblTempSassyInfo (Concat) SELECT (" & PartNumber & ") FROM [" & strSQL1 & "]"
MsgBox (strSQL2)
                                                                            
DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL2)
End Sub`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48005/discussion-between-hansup-and-user2887400)

Comment: Answer is:

  `strSQL2 = "INSERT INTO tblTempSassyInfo (Concat, TableName) SELECT PartNumber, FeederSize FROM [" & strSQL1 & "]" 
MsgBox (strSQL2) 

DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL2)`

Answer (score 1):

So, the user essentially wants 2 queries to run. A `DELETE * FROM Table` query, and an `Append` query. The user wants to know what table to utilize for the `Append` query by using the Combobox (may just be my assumption/interpretation). That being said, why not use something along the lines of:

```
If IsNull(Me.[Combo0].Value) Then
    MsgBox "Please select something."
    Me.[Combo0].SetFocus
    Cancel = True
Else
   Select Case Me.Form!Combo0
       Case 1
           DoCmd.OpenQuery "DeleteMaterialsTableData" 'Query to delete appropriate table data dependent on Combobox selection'
           DoCmd.OpenQuery "QueryNameMaterial1" 'Append records to appropriate table dependent on Combo0 selection'
       Case 2
           DoCmd.OpenQuery "DeleteMaterialsTableData" 'Query to delete appropriate table data dependent on Combobox selection'
           DoCmd.OpenQuery "QueryNameMaterial2" 'Append records to appropriate table dependent on Combo0 selection'
```

This is just trying to use the users' combobox values to determine which table to run the queries against, instead of the user trying to use the Combobox's value as a table name.

Answer (score 1):

You're pressing a button to do this.  This implies that some VBA code is running behind the scene (the Click event of the button).  In that case, the answer is a resounding Yes.

```
Dim strSQL as String
Dim strSQL2 as String

strSQL = "DELETE * FROM tblTempSassyInfo;"
DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

strSQL2 = "INSERT INTO tblTempSassyInfo (Concat, TableName, AddressName, PartNumber, [L/R], FeederSize, QtyPerBoard, SASSYname, RawBoard)
SELECT TableName & AddressName & PartNumber, TableName, AddressName, PartNumber, [L/R], FeederSize, QtyPerBoard, SassyName, RawBoard
FROM " & [FORMS]![DASHBOARD]![Combo0].SelectedValue & ";"
DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL2)
```

You may need to tweak that a bit, but it should get you pretty close.

You MAY need to use [FORMS]![DASHBOARD]![Combo0].Columns(0) or Columns(1) instead, I can't remember...

Answer (score 0):

As was stated; Access (and just about any brand database) can definitely do append and delete queries.

The problem is the design.  Specifically:
FROM [FORMS]![DASHBOARD]![Combo0];

From clause must be a record set (table) not a call to a control on a form.

My suggestion is to first establish a Select query that has the correct data that you want to append.  Save that with a name.  You need to be able to do this first.

Once that is done - then create an Append query that uses that saved Select query as its starting record set.

You then just need to trigger the Append query (the Select query will automatically run) using vba behind your button click event: 
Docmd.OpenQuery "Append Query Name"

Answer (score -1):

This is 100% possible in MS Access 2010 onward based on my experience. I've not used 2007, but MS says it is possible (see link below). I'm using parametrized queries in a few databases.

```
PARAMETERS  [forms].[dash].[dt_val] DateTime; 
SELECT a.F3 AS AdEnt, [forms].[dash].[dt_val] AS Expr1...
```

The important thing I've found is using a form the user will be interacting with and setting the Date as "DateTime" within the parameter. Here is a video from Microsoft that shows how to and says that it applies to 2007.

[Use Parameters in MS Access Queries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-parameters-in-queries-forms-and-reports-8209eb5c-1589-42e2-9b20-4181f4c7a356)

Additionally, if you want to do a delete or append, save it as a query then place a button on the form that executes the docmd.runquery for the name of that saved delete/append query.